# Binary Logistic Regression - How are my IVs affecting each other?

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, dataset, binary-data

I am a relative stats noob trying to create a binary logistic regression model in spss to explore the relationship between internet access and feeling part of your community. I am also interested in including smart phone ownership as an IV to see if that has an effect. Just to be clear, in this data set not all smart phone owners have access to the internet (around 90% do) and not everyone with access to the internet owns a smartphone.

The problem I have is that I am confused by the change in internet access sig and Exp(B) results when I take out smart phone ownership as an IV.

DV - Do you feel part of the community?
0 = No
1 = Yes

IV1 - Do you have access to the internet?
0 = No
1 = Yes

IV2 - Do you own a smart phone?
0 = No
1 = Yes

The following IVs are also included in the model because of their significant effect on feeling part of the community:

IV3 - Gender
0 = Male
1 = Female
2 = Other
3 = No Response

IV4 - Do you have a job?
0 = No
1 = Yes

IV5 - How long have you lived in the community?
Continuous variable

---

Model 1 with both Internet Access and Smart Phone Ownership:

[image]

Model 2 with only Internet Access:

[image]

Please can someone help me, I've been struggling to find explanations about what is going on here.
Why are there such big changes to the Exp(B)? What is going on between the IVs in the models and is the model more accurate when both are included?

And please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: The only weird thing seems to be for those answering gender with "other" or "no response".  You may have one each of these or perhaps some small number who all give the same answer to "Do you feel part of the community?".  In either case, you get perfect separation and silly coefficients.

Comment: Yes the no response and other categories is a small number of respondents issue. I just kept those in because I thought it was not affecting the results of different variables.

Comment: But @Henry can you explain what is happening between the internet and smart phone variables. Why are the results so different when they are both included vs only internet? And which model gives the 'true' results for the relationship between internet access and feeling part of the community?

Comment: There is no "truth" here. George Box said "Since all models are wrong, the scientist must be alert to what is importantly wrong" and variations on the same theme.  What you have here is many people who use both smartphones and the internet, some who use one, some the other, and some who use neither.  The average "feeling part of the community" varies between these groups, and your model is trying to fit the data as best it can; there is no implication of causality.  Your data suggests that the highest community group is one of the two using one but not both, which you can check.